# This python program is not giving me an output

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show

output_notebook()

p = figure(plot_width = 400, plot_height = 400)

p.circle([1,2,3,4,5], [4,7,1,6,3], size = 10, color = "navy", alpha = 0.5)

show(p)
```

this should show me a graph but I'm getting
`C:/python/python.exe "c:/Users/Harith A/work/project/hello.py"`
as the output

Comment: Are you using a notebook? It looks like you're running it as script

Comment: I am running it as script, should I use jupyter or something?

Comment: Yes, I'm not a specialist of `bokeh` but `output_notebook()` requires using a notebook

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this as scripts you could change to using `output_file` instead of `output_notebook`

Then the figure will be stored as a file.

Comment: Also, an amendment to @Rafael-WO's answer if I may, You will have to import output_file from under bokeh.plotting. However, neither output_file nor output_notebook are necessary if you run it as a script from your local fs.